# What is the inverse of chained :nots? (CSS grouped selectors)

Tags: css

Say I have a number of classes: `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four`.

You can select DIVs (for example) that have class `one` but not class `two`, `three`, or `four` with,

```
div.one:not(.two):not(.three):not(.four){}
```

How can you select the inverse of that (DIVs that have at least one of `two`, `three`, or `four`, but not `one`) in a single selector, or can't that be done?

I know it can be done with,

```
div.two:not(.one), div.three:not(.one), div.four:not(.one){}
```

but that's really a list of three selectors.

Comment: And you will be using these selectors. Maybe try re-classing elements to be able to select with single selector?

Comment: Can you use a single selector to select `div.one`, `div.two` and `div.three` from DOM? I think no... so you will have to use three selectors in your case as well.

Comment: @Justinas the real-life situation is messier than my distilled example, and I really need to use the classes that are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can you select the inverse of that in a single selector, or can't that be done?

We can use `:any()`

Currently a few browsers support [:any()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any) which will be later replaced by `:matches`

syntax as

```
:-moz-any( <selector># ) { style properties }
:-webkit-any( <selector># ) { style properties }
```

So your selector in the OP can be refactored to

```
div:-webkit-any(.two, .three, .four):not(.one)
```

Demo of `:any()` with the above syntax.

```css
div:-webkit-any(.two, .three, .four):not(.one) { /* webkit for chrome, moz for mozilla */ 
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

div{
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two one">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="four one">4</div>
```

[image]

**Future options.**

There is a under developing [:matches()](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/) selector

> The :matches pseudo-class is described as a functional pseudo-class by the official CSS Selectors Level 4 specifications. It doesn't serve any purpose in itself except making some complex selectors lighter by allowing them to be grouped. In a way, we can think as :matches as syntactic sugar.

With this we can do

```
div:matches(.two,.three,.four) :not(.one) { /*your styles*/}
```

**Other Options**

Add a common class to all your elements lets say `number`

Now you can do this

```
div.number:not(.one)
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer for me! I felt a bit embarrassed about asking such a question, but I'm glad I did now - I had no idea about :any() or :match(), and although they aren't practicable just now, I can adopt the additional class idea via a bit of JavaScript after the page has loaded.

Comment: @NickRice Glad to help.. :)